# How to change the Datatemplate which is used for CellTemplate of the GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

How to change the Datatemplate which is used for CellTemplate  of the GridViewColumn want to change to other datatemplate so that user can edit the value of the first column only when particular row is selected and focus is on textbox

I have created a sample app to reproduce the problem.

Here is the code in xaml file:

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>                    
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="View">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <GridView >
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Age">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                    </GridView>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>       
        <ListView x:Name="FoldersListView" Margin="3" SelectionMode="Single"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectCollection}"                  
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">

        </ListView>
     </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Below is in xaml.cs file

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public testVM VM = new testVM();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = VM;
        }     
    }

    public class testVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        List<emplyee> myProperty = new List<emplyee>();

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        public testVM()
        {
            objectCollection.Add(new emplyee() { Name = "aaa India",Age="10" });
            objectCollection.Add(new emplyee() { Name = "bbb India",Age="20" });
            objectCollection.Add(new emplyee() { Name = "ccc India",Age="30" });
            objectCollection.Add(new emplyee() { Name = "ddd India",Age="40" });
        }

        public List<emplyee> MyProperty { get{return myProperty;} }

        private ObservableCollection<emplyee> objectCollection = new ObservableCollection<emplyee>();
        public ObservableCollection<emplyee> ObjectCollection
        {
            get
            {


                return objectCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                objectCollection = value;

            }
        }


    }

    public class emplyee
    {
        public emplyee()
        {

        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }

    }
}
```

How to select the datatemplate dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

For selecting data templates dynamically, use the DataTemplateSelector class. You must override its SelectTemplate method.